# Retrofit 2 response

Tags: android, retrofit2

Не могу получить ответ с сервера. После того, как залогинился, получаю токен и информацию по Юзеру в таком формате:

```
{
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJlbWFpbCI6ImtoYWJpcm92cm9tYW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJraGFiaXJvdnJvbWFuQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTUwODU3MzkyNX0.JmtP3S_jZwnXo35Ha6EGSiH8tUdYjO-tph_mdRKVw4k",
"user": {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "Ivanovroman@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Roma",
    "last_name": "Ivanov"
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
@FormUrlEncoded 
@POST("auth/login/") Call<User> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

onClick:

```
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        okhttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okhttpClientBuilder.build())
                .build();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<User> call = apiInterface.login(email, password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                String token = response.body().getToken();
                Log.d(forlog, "token is - " + token);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(forlog, "This is fail");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Класс User

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String email;
private String password1;
private String password2;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private String patronymic_name;
private String token;

public User(String email, String first_name, String last_name, String patronymic_name, String password1, String password2) {
    this.email = email;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.patronymic_name = patronymic_name;
    this.password1 = password1;
    this.password2 = password2;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword1() {
    return password1;
}

public void setPassword1(String password1) {
    this.password1 = password1;
}

public String getPassword2() {
    return password2;
}

public void setPassword2(String password2) {
    this.password2 = password2;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getPatronymic_name() {
    return patronymic_name;
}

public void setPatronymic_name(String patronymic_name) {
    this.patronymic_name = patronymic_name;
}
```

Токен получаю, но не могу достать информацию о пользователе. Спасибо

Comment: Код класса `User` покажите.

Comment: Добавил в пост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неверно в вашем решении то, что сервер вам не отправляет `User` напрямую, а отправляет, назовем это `LoginResponse`, и эта структура (класс) содержит два поля: `String token` и `User user`.

Answer (score 0):

Создание класса LoginResponse с полями String token и User user полностью решило данную проблему. Спасибо

Class:

```
public class LoginResponse {
String token;
User user;

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public LoginResponse(String token, User user) {
    this.token = token;
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

Activity:

```
 Call<LoginResponse> call = apiInterface.login(email, password);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                                 Log.d(forlog, "token is - " + response.body().getToken());
                                 Log.d(forlog, "id is - " + response.body().getUser().getId());
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                             }
                         });
```